# Python,Tkinter, making a username/password interface

Tags: python, tkinter

Beginner to python. Can't seem to figure out how to set a password to these 
entries.Looked into a bunch of sites already. Any examples or feedback is much appreciated.Thanks...............................................

```
from tkinter import*
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import glob,os
root=Tk()


w1=Label(root,text="1")
w2=Label(root,text="2")
w3=Label(root,text="3")


e1=Entry(text="five")
e2=Entry(text="six")
e3=Entry(text="seven")

text=(e1)



def show_entry_fields():
    print("1:%s\n2:%s\n3:%s" %(e1.get(),e2.get(),e3.get()))
e1.delete(0,END)
e2.delete(0,END)
e3.delete(0,END)



b1=Button(root,text="Submit",command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3,column=3)


e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
e3.grid(row=2,column=1)


w1.grid(row=0)
w2.grid(row=1)
w3.grid(row=2)



image=Image.open("beer.png")
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label=Label(image=photo)
label.image=photo#keep a reference
label.grid(column=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: "set a password" meaning what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't seem to figure out how to set a password to these entries.

Going from your comment:

> rather set a password to each entry.

This might be more along the lines of what you are attempting to do.

The below code will check if each entry field has the correct password.
if so it prints success and if not it prints try again.

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()

Label(root, text="1").grid(row=0)
Label(root, text="2").grid(row=1)
Label(root, text="3").grid(row=2)

e1=Entry(root)
e2=Entry(root)
e3=Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
e3.grid(row=2,column=1)

def test_entry_fields():
    if e1.get() == "five" and e2.get() == "six" and e3.get() == "seven":
        print("You have entered the correct passwords!")
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)
    e3.delete(0,END)

b1=Button(root,text="Submit",command=test_entry_fields).grid(row=3,column=3)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.However i do not intend to show the text at the start of the program rather set a password to each entry. if that makes any sense.

Comment: Are you trying to validate each entry field with a different password?

Comment: @Hauk I have added a 3rd example to my answer. Let me know if that is closer to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have updated my answer and removed the unrelated portion. Please select the check box next to the answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a "mask" to cover the input of a password field, for example "Hunter2" becomes "*******" then use this.

```
show="*"
```

-> replacing * with whichever char you want to use as a mask.

for example, to use the second textbox you have as a password field.

```
e2=Entry(text="six", show="*")
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Does the argument `text="six"` work here? Its likely not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: i'm just adding the "show" part to what they had there, im assuming they have their reasons

Comment: Well to be clear it is not valid. You would be better of removing from your answer for accuracy reasons. It might server to confuse the reader if you leave it in.